# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException in Spring Integration

Tags: xml, spring-integration

I have one Spring Integration Application with some below settings.

```
<int:gateway id="person" service-interface="<package.name>.service.PersonService">
    <int:method name="selectFromPerson"
                request-channel="selectRequestChannel"
                request-timeout="5000"
                reply-channel="selectResponseChannel"
                reply-timeout="5000"/>  
    <int:method name="insertIntoEXPerson"
                request-channel="insertRequestChannel"                  
                request-timeout="5000"
                reply-channel="insertResponseChannel"
                reply-timeout="5000"/>                              
</int:gateway>
```

Later 
some where in Java code, I am writing

```
final AbstractApplicationContext context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:META-INF/spring/integration/*-context.xml");

context.registerShutdownHook();
final PersonService personService = context.getBean(PersonService.class);
```

When I am trying to run this application on WINDOWS, Its working perfectly fine but in UNIX box its not running and showing below error.

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [<package.name>.service.PersonService] is defined: expected single bean but found 0:
```

Any idea how can I make it run on UNIX box too?

Comment: The OS shouldn't make any difference. It's probably a classpath problem. If you turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework` you'll see lots of debug logs for loading application contexts and bean loading. If it can't find the file, try adding `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"))` to see the actual classpath; finally, run the jvm with `-verbose` to see where classes are being loaded from.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell, This UNIX box is nothing but my companies testing server so I cant really run any command there. But still I can see my full classpath somehow. I am seeing my project's jar in classpath entries.

Comment: There's something wrong with the environment; if you can't get a debug log it will be hard to diagnose.

Comment: Debug log is too big @GaryRussell :)

Comment: You only need to DEBUG the bean creation; that won't be big, especially because the app fails to start.

Comment: Yeah, I think you already know this but still before anything I give you some background. I don't have any implementation of my interface.
And in logs I just roughly searched for my bean "PersonService" and I am only finding this text in error area. i.e org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [<package.name>.service.PersonService] is defined: expected single bean but found 0:

Comment: Yes; Spring Integration generates the implementation for you. Like I said, you need to look at the bean creation log and compare it to the one that works. There's something different in the environment; more than the OS.

Comment: @GaryRussell, I compared both classpaths and the jar in them. When I am running my application from main(), in this case number of jars are less than when I run the same on server. Obviously, there are some other projects also for which jars are also coming into target(from where server is loading). Can it be a cause?

Comment: As I have said several times now, you need to compare the bean creation logging between the two environments. Please do that before making additional comments. I cannot help you otherwise.